# How can I exclude specific DB objects from having JPA annotations generated for them?

Tags: jooq

I have the following configuration which works well for me:

```java
return new org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration()
  .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
    .withDriver(dataSourceDriver)
    .withUrl(dataSourceUrl)
    .withUser(username)
    .withPassword(password))
  .withGenerator(new Generator()
     .withName(CustomJooqGenerator.class.getCanonicalName())

    // Generation options, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/
    .withGenerate(new Generate()
      /* ******************************************
       *        Class/Record Generation Option
       * ******************************************/
      // Generate jOOQ Record classes for type-safe querying. You can turn
      // this off, if you don't need "active records" for CRUD.
      .withRecords(true)

      // Generate POJOs in addition to Record classes for usage of the
      // ResultQuery.fetchInto(Class) API.
      .withPojos(true)

      // Generate data access objects (DAOs) in addition to other classes.
      .withDaos(true)

      /* ******************************************
       *           Annotation Generation
       * - see https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-annotations/
       * ******************************************/
      // Place the javax.annotation.Generated annotation on generated java files
      // to indicate the jOOQ version used for source code. Defaults to true.
      .withGeneratedAnnotation(true)

      // Possible values for generatedAnnotationType:
      // DETECT_FROM_JDK | JAVAX_ANNOTATION_GENERATED |
      // JAVAX_ANNOTATION_PROCESSING_GENERATED
      .withGeneratedAnnotationType(DETECT_FROM_JDK)

      // Annotate POJOs and Records with JPA annotations for increased
      // compatibility and better integration with JPA/Hibernate, etc
      .withJpaAnnotations(true)
      .withJpaVersion("2.2")

      // Annotate POJOs and Records with JSR-303 validation annotations.
      .withValidationAnnotations(true)

      // Spring annotations can be applied on DAOs for better Spring integration. These include:
      // @Autowired, and @Repository.
      .withSpringAnnotations(true))
    .withDatabase(new Database()
      .withName("org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase")
      .withIncludes(".*")
      .withExcludes(getExcludeList())
      // Remove withSchemata to generate for every schema and catalogue.
      // Currently, this has issues with type generation for the default
      // catalogue, so we pass in a list of schemas we are interested in.
      .withSchemata(getSchemas())

      // See: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/
      // Forces certain DB types to be mapped to Java types.
      .withForcedTypes(getForcedTypes())
    )
    .withTarget(new Target()
      .withPackageName(generatedSourcesOutputPackageName)
      .withDirectory(generationOutputDir)))
  ;
```

I am aware this is missing the definitions of certain fields/getters but please ignore that and my extra comments (they are not relevant to the question).

I know we can use the `withExcludes` option to give a regular expression which indicates what database objects we want to exclude from the database generation. In the config above I have the following config:

```java
      .withExcludes(getExcludeList())
```

This works well to exclude database objects completely from the auto-generated classes. However, my question is: is there an option I can use similar to the one above which indicates to simply exclude a generated class from including JPA annotations? I still want those database objects to have classes generated, but I don't want them to have JPA annotations. Currently I use the options:

```java
  .withJpaAnnotations(true)
  .withJpaVersion("2.2")
```

These options generate JPA annotations on basically everything (views, table-valued functions, etc). And I would like to avoid it being generated for certain, unnecessary database objects.

Maybe something like:

```java
  .withJpaAnnotations(true)
  .withJpaVersion("2.2")
  .withJpaAnnotationsExcludes(...)
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. But go ahead and open a feature request: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Unless I'm overlooking a compelling use case for this (I'm curious about this, you didn't mention it, @vab2048), I don't see that getting on top of any priority queue - there are many more interesting feature requests on the roadmap. Besides, it's relatively easy to implement.

Comment: @ Lukas Eder this was mainly because the JPA Table and Entity annotations were being generated for table valued functions and views. As would be expected no JPA annotations for a primary key are added to those classes. As a result Hibernate complains about invalid entity definitions (JPA spec says they must have an @Id field defined). Excluding those classes from having JPA annotations generated for them is the simplest way to get things working with Hibernate/Spring boot.

Comment: @vab2048: I see, interesting. Updatable views can definitely behave like entities. jOOQ doesn't know yet whether a view is updatable (hoping this will be available in the future). Table valued functions are probably not entities, althought the canonical example shown by most blogs advertising JPA's "stored procedure capabilities" always shows of `SYS_REFCURSOR` usage, in case of which an actual entity is being produced. jOOQ "abuses" JPA annotations instead of introducing its own, without inheriting the entire semantics of JPA, let alone implement the spec...

Comment: @vab2048: Having said so, I don't think it's a good idea to use jOOQ-generated POJOs that are JPA-annotated as actual JPA entities. Better use Hibernate's code generator, or write them manually.

Comment: @LukasEder I agree. I manually write the entities I am interested in. This issue cropped up because of the packaging structure of my spring boot app meaning that the generated classes are automatically picked up. Simply amending my jooq config as you suggested in your answer helped me get everything to work without having to undergo a major package rename/restructure. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I see, I haven't though of that, thanks for pointing this out. Would it be possible to exclude all of the jOOQ-generated "entities" from being picked up by Spring Boot, then?

Comment: The printColumnJPAAnnotation you pointed out in your answer is perfect for me. Not having the @Entity/@Table annotation but having the @Column ones is great because it fixes the problems and aids in documentation. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box configuration for this, but in this particular case, you can relatively easily achieve the wanted behaviour by overriding the `org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator` class and two of its methods (you seem to be doing this already):

```java
public class CustomJooqGenerator extends JavaGenerator {
    @Override
    protected void printTableJPAAnnotation(JavaWriter out, TableDefinition table) {
        if (someCondition)
            super.printTableJPAAnnotation(out, table);
        else
            ; // Don't do anything
    }

    @Override
    protected void printColumnJPAAnnotation(JavaWriter out, ColumnDefinition column) {
        if (someCondition)
            super.printColumnJPAAnnotation(out, column);
        else
            ; // Don't do anything
    }
}
```